# Code inside the Html P tag is displaying output in two different line in Safari browser

Tags: html, css, safari

i am a newbie html developer. The below code displays output perfectly in a line in chrome browser, but not in safari browser.Code inside the Html P tag is displaying output in two different line in Safari browser.From my end i tried everything i could do, but no success.Can anyone help me to fix it? For reference i am attaching screenshot of chrome screen as well as safari screen.

```css
.contactcard {
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 25px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contact-section .contact-images {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contactcard .contactcontents h4 {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.contactcard .contactcontents p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="contactcard">
      <div class="contactcontents">
        <div class="contact-images">
          <img src="images/icon/contact.jpg" alt="Contact-details" title="Quick contact">
        </div>
        <h4>quick contact</h4>
        <p>Ph: +123 4567 8910<br>Email: info@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Chrome image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re6mF.jpg)
[safari image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TVzt.jpg)

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] (including the relevant CSS).

Comment: Hi, this the minimal code i have, i have updated all the relevant css.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/asFr6EJ — I can't reproduce the problem in Safari 14.1.1

Comment: @Quentin please check this url on safari and just scroll down https://rawcodev.com/contact-us.html

Comment: I can't reproduce it there either.

Comment: @Quentin  what can be the issue> i tried with 3 iphones & 2 mackbook (chrome is perfect, but in  safari not working..its going to next line.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="contactcard">
      <div class="contactcontents">
        <div class="contact-images">
          <img src="images/icon/contact.jpg" alt="Contact-details" title="Quick contact">
        </div>
        <h4>quick contact</h4>
        <p>Ph: +123 4567 8910</p>
        <p>Email: info@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```